# Android app closes whenever i click on button

Tags: java, android, xml

i'm building an app for my project in which it contains a layout which opens the camera and takes photo while other converts text to speech, whenever I click on the button which navigates to text to speech  layout , the app is closing and I cannot reach that layout

text to speech code works fine when separately tested in a new project but when linked as a navigating page by button it closes

//code of java //

```
     public class Text extends AppCompatActivity {


     Button ak,bk;
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.text);
    ak=(Button)findViewById(R.id.cam);
    ak.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i=new Intent(Text.this,Camera.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
    bk=(Button)findViewById(R.id.spe);
    bk.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent k=new Intent(Text.this,Speech.class);
            startActivity(k);
        }
    });
}
```

//code of xml//

```
 <RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    tools:context=".major.Text">
    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/spe"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"


        android:text="text to speech"
        android:textColor="#2976d5"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/cam"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"

        android:layout_marginTop="190dp"
        android:text="camera"
        android:textColor="#2976d5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

//code of text to speech java class

```
public class Speech extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button b1;
    EditText ed1;
    TextToSpeech t1;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ed1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

        t1 = new TextToSpeech(getApplicationContext(), new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInit(int status) {
                if (status != TextToSpeech.ERROR) {
                    t1.setLanguage(Locale.UK);
                }
            }
        });

        b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String toSpeak = ed1.getText().toString();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), toSpeak, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                t1.speak(toSpeak, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH,null);
            }
        });
    }

    public void onPause() {
        if (t1 != null) {
            t1.stop();
            t1.shutdown();
        }
        super.onPause();
    }
}
```

//logcat:

```
     2019-10-06 20:15:53.294 20959-21006/com.example.omen.loginmajor 
     E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000082da
     2019-10-06 20:15:53.294 20959-21006/com.example.omen.loginmajor 
     E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000082da
```

the app keeps closing instead of going to another page

Comment: When you application crashes, you need to provide the Logcat for us to determine the reason for the crash. It's difficult to investigate by looking at the source code.

Comment: you might try setting the function calls outside of the on create block...  sometimes calls to specific android functions are prohibited in the oncreate...  just a thought...  probably wrong.

Comment: If i have understood the question right, it's about regression testing of an existing Android application which is not working correct. Unfortunately, it wasn't given in the original posting which kind of GUI testing framework was used. Or if a theorem prover like ACL2 was utilized for formal verification of the software system.

Comment: There are many possible causes for the crash. For example if you forgot to add the Activity classes to your manifest file the app will crash or if you do not check for permissions to use the camera. To help you out we need the correct logcat output. The part you posted is not very helpful. There should be some section starting with something like `AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION:` which is highlighted in red and spans over multiple lines.

Comment: E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000082da
this error is related to GL, try running your app once by disabling hardware acceleration

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can change

> Intent k=new Intent(**Text.this**,Speech.class);

to

> Intent k=new Intent(**getApplicationContext()**,Speech.class);